# Check frontpage of joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I was read the instruction from joomla, that if I want to check the current page is front page like below

```
    <?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

But, when I practised this instruction. The text "This is the front page" is always showed on all pages. How this can happen on my joomla.

Comment: Can you post copy/pasted code from your template how it looks? And how does your menu structure look?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to check the front page with this code:

```
if (JUri::getInstance()->toString() == JUri::base()) { ... }
```

Comment: to @Dmitry Rekun thank you for your solution. This what I want.

Comment: Great approach, thank you!
$menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault() will pass as long as the component/view combination is the same as the homepage menu item, regardless of extra parameters that may be added.